# Steering Behavior Seeking

Tags: steering-behaviors

I am trying put a seek feature in my code.

Just frame code, not actual code.

```
 Seek(TargetPos)
{
  Vector2D DesiredVelocity = Normalize(TargetPos - currentPos)*MaxSpeed();

  return (DesiredVelocity - currentVelocity}
```

Simply when I press 2, it will change the target, 3 will change the target and so on...

Do I need to make the currentVelocity the old Desired velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could make `currentVelocity` equal to `DesiredVelocity`.

However, this is going to make your object suddenly change direction in an unrealistic manner. If you want your object to travel more realistically, you should try interpolating from `currentVelocity` to `DesiredVelocity`, and set that to `currentVelocity`.

Answer (score 0):

You  do not need to make the `currentVelocity` equal the old `desiredVelocity`.

`desiredVelocity` changes every frame, as the actor changes position in relation to it's target.

Here's an overview of the situation:
[image: seek/flee vectors]

You could use the resulting `steeringDirection` to calculate an incremental change to the current velocity (as per [Steering Behaviors For Autonomous Characters](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/)):

```
steeringDirection = seek (targetPos);

// this limits the steering force to a maximum steering force
// to avoid unnatural quick 180 turns
steeringForce = truncate (steeringDirection, MaxForce);

// we calculate an acceleration using the actor's mass
// so bigger things can be slow and have "more inertia"
// while small seekers can be fast and more maneuverable
acceleration = steeringForce / mass;

// and add it to the current velocity, which we then clamp to
// the maximum speed of the actor
currentVelocity = truncate (currentVelocity + acceleration, MaxSpeed);

// and we update the position
position = position + currentVelocity;
```

Hope I could help shed some light on the situation :)